# How to install ImageMagick on Windows 8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm trying to setup ImageMagick so I can use the Paperclip gem for Ruby on Rails. I've looked at pretty much every question on StackOverflow about the issue, but they all just skip over my issue, that none of the ImageMagick commands are recognized on the CommandPrompt.

I downloaded and then installed ImageMagick-7.0.1-1-Q16-x64-dll.exe on [this page](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

I installed the program to my C: directory, so that there wouldn't be an issue with spaces in the Path, and I used all default installation selections and even selected "Install development headers" which some answers said to do. My issue is that when ImageMagick finishes installing, and it says to test some commands (like "convert -version) on Command Prompt, they all result in

> "'convert' is not recognized as an internal or external command ...."

On the command prompt. What could be an issue? Every step-by-step tutorial automatically assumes that these commands are recognized. Most troubleshooting involves steps afterwards.

[Here's the documentation for paperclip.](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/4.3.6) All I have to do is make sure the gem has access to ImageMagick, by putting in the development.rb file:

> Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"

In order to find that path above, however, the documentation says to type "which convert". I've researched this and apparently that's a Unix command, and not something for Windows.

So basically, what steps do I need to take so that paperclip has access to ImageMagick? Why aren't basic ImageMagick commands recognized, even after a completed installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install ImageMagick under Windows, they is a button you need to check that tells the script to install "legacy" utilities such as convert. Reinstall, click on this button, and convert is ready to use. Alternatively, install ImageMagick 6.X which deploys convert automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Windows users, I've answered most of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45596081/5604404).

The windows command line won't run `which convert`.  You'll need to use something like git bash.

Reinstalling image magick won't hurt.  You could try another file. I know the dll one (you mentioned) is top of the list, the next one is 64bit as well.  You must check every option at install as paperclip will use lots of image magick functionality behind the scenes so check all options. Then restart the system.

Answer (score -1):

in command before typing convert you have to type in  magick  then convert

keep in mind you are using a newer version of IM hence you have to start by typing 'magick' and then follow other command