# Image Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError #Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm getting tired of this error...
I tried everything that's on the internet (that I found so far)

Gem

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.6'
```

config/environments/development.rb

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/c/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16/"
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'
```

path for ImageMagick/convert

```
https://gyazo.com/2e8714546606b796b63f5b64663cab31
```

file.exe it installed

```
https://gyazo.com/5d0d3d5723c52e6cc812d72202ba4038
```

my model

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>"}
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late.
Lots of people with this issue are running Windows.

1. Image Magick should be installed correctly (all options selected during install). It is a big step to reinstall and reboot so leave this option until last.
2. Open `config/environments/development.rb`
3. Add the following line: `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'.  You check the path (mine is shown) by running `which convert` at the command line.  Not the command line that ships with windows.  I run git bash.
4. Restart your Rails server
5. Check your model.  My syntax in app\models\post.rb was

   `has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }`

which I changed to

`has_attached_file :image, style: { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }`

6. You may find the error goes but the image is not showing.  Check your code in the show page.

   - If I remove (:medium) the image shows fine.
   - It doesn't show when I leave the code like below (Haml, sorry!)

`= image_tag @recipe.image.url(:medium), class: "recipe_image"`